# Bad merge syntax in Python? f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I am trying the following:

```
df2.groupby(['A']).max('Delta')
```

And getting this error:

```
f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Added context: That snippet is from the following fuller code works fine in my ipynb (Python 3) but not in an embedded script also using Python v3.

```
df3 = df2.merge(df2.groupby(['A']).max('Delta').reset_index()[['A','Delta']],how='left',on='A',suffixes=("","_max")).merge(df2.groupby(['A']).min('Delta').reset_index()[['A','Delta']],how='left',on='A',suffixes=("","_min"))
```

I've also tried:

```
df2.groupby(['A']).max(['Delta'])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) takes named arguments.

By providing e.g. `'Delta'` you're giving it a second, positional argument.

The first positional argument is the instance of the [`DataFrameGroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returned by `groupby`.